# Is there an alternative to putting technical analysis calculations inside for loops in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, rsi

I am running into the following issue with my code:
**
Warning at 259:21 The function 'ta.rsi' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope**

I want to see if RSI dipped below 40 at any point while a pullback was happening. I don't see how I could check this without performing an RSI calculation with a for loop. I already have the start and stop bars of the pullback and whether it was a positive or negative pullback. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

````
getRSIStatus(startBar, endBar, pullbackType) =>
    status = "neutral"

    var float rsiValue = na
    for i = startBar to endBar
        rsiValue := ta.rsi(close[i], 14)

        isPositivePullback = pullbackType == "up"
        if (isPositivePullback and rsiValue > 60)
            status := "overbought"
            break
        else if (not isPositivePullback and rsiValue < 40)
            status := "oversold"
            break
    status```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator("stk",overlay=true)
getRSI(cl,len)=>
    ta.rsi(cl,len)
getRSIStatus(startBar, endBar, pullbackType) =>
    status = "neutral"

    var float rsiValue = na
    for i = startBar to endBar
        rsiValue := getRSI(close[i],14)

        isPositivePullback = pullbackType == "up"
        if (isPositivePullback and rsiValue > 60)
            status := "overbought"
            break
        else if (not isPositivePullback and rsiValue < 40)
            status := "oversold"
            break
    status
plot(ta.vwap(close))
```

Moving RSI fetch part to another method will resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know that was possible. God bless your heart

Comment: Actually that results in the same error being thrown; I dont think functions in the 'ta' library are allowed to be called at all in a loop. I think I will resort to making an array of all instances of RSI crossing the threshhold as the script is running and reference it as necessary

Comment: I have an useful RSI indicator with code. If you like please use the below from  TV. https://in.tradingview.com/script/GHWmMyx8-RSIWithOverBoughtAndOverSoldCondition/